# How to use NodeJS to query psql database with multiple WHERE conditions based on user input

Tags: node.js

I am creating a full stack application that uses NodeJS, Express, and PSQL. My application is a POS system that should be able to view the orders taken by the restaurant. My troubles lie in the query of the get request that I am sending to the database to fetch. I have a table named `cabo_grill` that holds the orders, and there is a column named `type` that indicates whether it is a protein, tortilla, side, etc. So far I have hard coded `SELECT * FROM cabo_grill WHERE (type = 'protein');` However, I want to modify this query to accommodate for the options that user selects. For instance, if the user selects the options: tortilla, side, I would want the query to be `SELECT * FROM cabo_grill WHERE (type = 'tortilla' OR type = 'side');` However I am unsure how to do this. This is the code that I have right now for the query:

```
    async getInventoryItem(type) {
            try {
                const response = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    const query = "SELECT * FROM cabo_grill WHERE (type = ? AND id > 0) ORDER BY id ASC;";
                    connection.query(query, [type], (err, results) => {
                        if (err)
                            reject(new Error(err.message));
                        else
                            resolve(results);
                    });
                });
                return response;
            } 
            catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        }
```

The get request:

```
app.get('/getInventoryItem/:type', (request, response) => {
    const { type } = request.params;
    const db = dbService.getDbServiceInstance();
    const result = db.getInventoryItem(type);
    result
    .then(data => response.json({data : data}))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
})
```

processing on the front end:

```
function fetchAllInventory() {
    fetch('https://project3-7bzcyqo3va-uc.a.run.app/getAllInventory') 
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => loadHTMLTable(data['data']));
}
var allButton = document.getElementById('allBtn');
allButton.addEventListener('click', fetchAllInventory);
```

**TLDR**: How can I get my code to append type = '..' to the query depending on the button that is clicked for the menu options.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using following syntax to simplify logic:

```
value IN (selection1,selection2,...)
```

Without use of an ORM you'll need to use some form of interpolation with template literals (include remaining context of query). Assuming selections an array of options chosen:

```
`value IN (${selections.join(',')}`
```

That said, tool like knex.js could prove helpful in cases like these.